# How to Add Google Adsense in Angular 8 Website?

Tags: angular, single-page-application, progressive-web-apps, angular8, server-side-rendering

I have an website https://www.aman-g.com/blog Developed using Angular Framework (v8). I have also implemented ssr(service side rendering) using Angular Universal. And PWA (Progressive Web App). And Using Firebase Hosting.

I have also an Google Adsense Account approved for another website. Which is not available.
I want to add Google Adsense in my Angular website.
Can any help how can I do this??

Comment: I did it myself 

Comment: Be careful, it might be against their policies

Comment: oke bro!!! but it is not against their policies.

Comment: can you explain how its done please

Comment: can you guide how to implement?